# OpenIddict Asp.net Core 5.0 How to Get Principal Associated in Refresh Token Flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, openiddict

I'm using the refresh token flow and it's working as designed where I can get a refresh token and then use it to get a new access token.

When the new access token is generated on the refresh token call I want to access the OpenIddictTokens.Id of the newly generated access token.

I thought I could do this using the OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponseContext event as shown below, but the Principal returned is null, so I can't get at the Token Id.

I have tried a bunch of other Server and Validation events, but can't seem to find an event which will allow me to get the token id of the new access token. Am I missing something?

```
.AddServer(options =>
{
   ....
   options
       .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
       // .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
       //     .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

   options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponseContext>(builder =>
       builder.UseInlineHandler(
           context =>
           {
               var principal = context.Principal; //Principal is null
               principal.GetTokenId();
               return default;

           })
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried a bunch of other Server and Validation events, but can't seem to find an event which will allow me to get the token id of the new access token. Am I missing something?

You can use the `ProcessSignIn` event that has a `RefreshTokenPrincipal`. Just make sure to register your event handler with a high order to ensure the token identifier is attached to the principal before your handler is invoked.